# Pushwoosh can not delete message created by API

Tags: api, pushwoosh

**EDIT: as noted in the answer below, this was a problem on the pushwoosh side, it has been fixed!**

When I create a push message through the pushwoosh API (using `/createTargetedMessage`) I'm not able to delete the message through the API. Messages made with the pushwoosh interface can be deleted through the API, no prob...

These are the steps I took to produce this error:

### 1. Create push message with the following params

```
{
   "request":{
      "auth":"AUTH TOKEN",
      "send_date":"2015-09-22 15:07",
      "content":{
         "nl":"teststsdfgh",
         "en":"teststsdfgh"
      },
      "devices_filter":"A(\"8A1EB-4E875\") * T(\"inholidaypark\", BETWEEN, [\"2015-09-22 00:00\",\"2015-09-22 23:59\"]) * T(\"Language\", IN, [\"nl\", \"en\"])"
   }
}
```

### 2. This returns the following response; the `messageCode` is stored in our local DB for later use

```
{
  "status":200,
  "response":{
    "status_code":200,
    "status_message":"OK",
    "response":
      "messageCode":"D3F6-60769243-68B30EA8"
    }
  }
}
```

### 3. Call `/deleteMessage` with following data

```
{
    "request":{
        "auth":"AUTH TOKEN",
        "message": "D3F6-60769243-68B30EA8"
    }
}
```

### 4. API keeps returning:

```
{
  "status_code": 210,
  "status_message": "Message not found",
  "response": null
}
```

But when I look at the push history the message is there (with the same messageCode and all). And it can be deleted through the pushwoosh interface, but not through the API.

---

**On a side note**: when the message is sent, we can obviously no longer delete it, then the API returns a more or less correct error:

```
{
  "status_code": 210,
  "status_message": "Forbidden",
  "response": null
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just FYI for the rest of the readers, this issue has been identified and fixed on Pushwoosh side.

Move Along, Nothing to See Here. :)